# pre-populate multifield and text field dynamically in cq5 dialog

Tags: extjs, aem

I want to pre populate the multifield of cq5 dialog with read only text fields. My component picks up data from child pages and displays it on the parent page, the author must be able to modify the order in which they are displayed ; so i want the dialog to have a multifield with text fields already containing title of child pages so author can use the send to top/down functionality of multifield to modify the order.

Can u guys please suggest ways to do this, i know selection xtype has this functionality through json options provider.Can this be done with a multifield ?

This is my first question and i am a newbie to cq5 so forgive any mistakes in the question. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to extend the multifield xtype or create a new one, create a client lib referencing your JS file (fastest approach: use cq.widgets for the client lib category, will only be imported in authoring environment), add in ExtJS configs to handle your logic (disabled state), and then reference that new xtype in your component dialog.

- Example of a custom multifield: http://cq.shishank.info/2011/12/19/multifield-with-custom-xtype/ (with commentary... http://forums.adobe.com/message/4332833)
- API doc for disabling textfields: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-cfg-disabled (`Ext.form.TextField` inherits from `Ext.form.Field`)

You will need some degree of JavaScript knowledge to get this working, but enough tinkering should be suffice.

Comment: I have customized a multifield widget by extending Multifield using CQ.Ext.extend(CQ.form.MultiField . However on adding disable:true to textfield or on the customized multifield it stops author to reorder or remove  the items in the multifield. Let me know if anyone is facing this issue and has a solution on this?

Comment: You may need to change the behavior of reorder/remove buttons to ignore disabled states. However you may be also disabling the wrong element or not specifying to only the input field (which is what the issue sounds like).

Comment: thanks Matt Lo, the first link u have given has helped me customize the xtype within the multi field (element within the field config). what i want is the multifield field have the fields added dynamically without the author having to click on the plus icon, can u please give me pointers on how to achieve it.

Comment: You're going to have to program that from the ExtJS layer. (probably have to read from the JCR via CQ Query API)